# @ApiModelProperty(hidden = true) is ignored on join columns

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

`@ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)` is ignored if the property is a Class. My problem is that it expands too much and a leaf field becomes required.

Is there a way to make it work? Or the only solution is to make a different class for request usages?

A simple example:

```
public class Child {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}


public class Parent {
    private String name;

    @ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)
    private Child child;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Child getChild() {
        return child;
    }

    public void setChild(Child child) {
        this.child = child;
    }
}
```

If I put `@ModelAttribute` over `Parent`, in rest endpoint swagger will render the `child.name` field in the request.
[image]

Comment: post swagger api doc screenshot

Comment: Added image in description